# jquery: run script without affecting divs with same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Got a product loop, where I need to change images on click. Like in every product loop, there is a whole bunch of divs with same classes. Which in my case get affected. Can't isolated them. Initial image does disappear. But not a single one, that's intended, but all of them. And no new images appear

html of the single product

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="galwrap displaytable">
        <div class=" galitem galitem1"></div>
        <div class=" galitem galitem2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="displaytable galcolors">
        <div class="displaytablecell galcolor galcolor1"></div>
        <div class="displaytablecell galcolor galcolor2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and jquery

```
$(".product").each(function () {
    $(this).find(".galcolor2").click(function () {
        $(".galitem").hide();
        $(this).parent().find(".galitem2").show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h1twaf1y/

Comment: You're probably going to need to exclusively use the DOM methods (.parent(), .sibling(), etc.) and forget about the class selector altogether in this case. Can you post a "working" js fiddle of what you have so far (use can replace images with background colors to save time/complexity)? I could probably get it to work from that point on.

Comment: Your click event only goes up one parent level to .galcolors, which does not contain galitem2. You need to go up TWO levels with parent().parent() instead. Please see my answer.

Comment: @whaaaaaaz Change it to parent().parent() instead, look at http://jsfiddle.net/h1twaf1y/1/ and my answer

Comment: what exactly is the total behavior you expect? Fiddle isn't very defintitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/q72nw00t/2/

Javascript:

```
$(".galcolor2").click(function(){
    $(".galitem").hide();
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".galitem2").show();
});
```

HTML: (this is just a section repeated over and over again)

```
<div class="product">
<div class="galwrap displaytable">
 <div class=" galitem galitem1">this will be hidden</div>
 <div class=" galitem galitem2" style="display: none">this will be shown</div>
</div>   
<div class="displaytable galcolors">
 <div class="displaytablecell galcolor galcolor1"></div>
 <div class="displaytablecell galcolor galcolor2">click this</div>
</div>
</div>
----------
<div class="product">
<div class="galwrap displaytable">
 <div class=" galitem galitem1">this will be hidden</div>
 <div class=" galitem galitem2" style="display: none">this will be shown</div>
</div>   
<div class="displaytable galcolors">
 <div class="displaytablecell galcolor galcolor1"></div>
 <div class="displaytablecell galcolor galcolor2">click this</div>
</div>
</div>
----------
<div class="product">
<div class="galwrap displaytable">
 <div class=" galitem galitem1">this will be hidden</div>
 <div class=" galitem galitem2" style="display: none">this will be shown</div>
</div>   
<div class="displaytable galcolors">
 <div class="displaytablecell galcolor galcolor1"></div>
 <div class="displaytablecell galcolor galcolor2">click this</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Basically you want to listen for any clicks on ALL .galcolor2, then when that is clicked, hide all .galitem, and then only show the RELATED .galitem2 by going up two levels to the div.product and finding the correct item

The problem in your initial code, is that you only went up ONE level with parent() to div.galcolors where you should have instead went up TWO levels with parent().parent(), up to div.product.

Comment: this script, however still has one of my problems, where on click, all elements disappear. Thanks for pointing out the parent mistake though.

Comment: I thought you wanted everything to disappear. If not, then use parent().parent() on the hide() and it will work http://jsfiddle.net/q72nw00t/2/

Answer is changed

Comment: dang. that easy... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to find .galitem relative to the item clicked, the way you can find that is to use `$.closest()`. Closest will travel up the DOM tree (starting with the current node) until it finds a matching selector, which is much better than using parent because you're not dependent on the DOM structure making your code less brittle and easier to read. So your code would look like this instead:

```js
$(".product").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".galcolor2").click(function(){
        $(".galitem").hide();
        $(this).closest(".product").find(".galitem2").show();
    });
});
```